# Basis of rowspace

Tags: linear-algebra

How to find a basis of a rowspace of a matrix sized mxn? Explain it thoroughly and WHY would you use that way!

I know how to find a basis for a rowspace, by reducing it into rref and I also understood that the row operations don't change the rowspace at all. But the question is: WHY? Why would I use the row operations? Help me, please. Thank you!

Comment: If your goal is to find a basis for the rowspace the why is already answered. Indeed, as you say, row operations preserve the rowspace and the non-zero rows in the RREF are linearly independent, so this gives a method for finding such a basis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One advantage of using row operations is exactly as you said: to put a matrix in RREF, and there are several advantages in having a matrix in RREF, for example it is easier to solve systems of linear equations; if you are given an invertible matrix, by performing the same row operations on the identity that you use to put the matrix in RREF, you get the inverse of the original matrix; also having a matrix in RREF makes it much easier to find the dimension of the row space, it's simply the number of non-zero rows in RREF.I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Adding a scalar multiple of a row to a matrix doesn't change the determinant:

$$\begin{pmatrix}
a_{11}&a_{12}&a_{13}\\
a_{21}&a_{22}&a_{23}\\
a_{31}&a_{32}&a_{33}
\end{pmatrix}
+k
\begin{pmatrix}
a_{21}&a_{22}&a_{23}\\
0&0&0\\
0&0&0
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
a_{11}+ka_{21}&a_{12}+ka_{22}&a_{13}+ka_{23}\\
a_{21}&a_{22}&a_{23}\\
a_{31}&a_{32}&a_{33}
\end{pmatrix}
$$

because $\det(A+B)=\det(A)$ in this case.